# Datanode and namenode not running

Tags: hadoop

This is the result of jps.

```
ibrahim@Fatima:~$ jps
24019 SecondaryNameNode
24293 NodeManager
24692 Jps
24167 ResourceManager

ibrahim@Fatima:~$ netstat -plten | grep java
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:50090           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1000       185862      24019/java      
tcp6       0      0 :::8088                 :::*                    LISTEN      1000       190431      24167/java      
tcp6       0      0 :::8030                 :::*                    LISTEN      1000       187327      24167/java      
tcp6       0      0 :::8031                 :::*                    LISTEN      1000       187319      24167/java      
tcp6       0      0 :::8032                 :::*                    LISTEN      1000       187758      24167/java      
tcp6       0      0 :::8033                 :::*                    LISTEN      1000       190439      24167/java      
tcp6       0      0 :::45700                :::*                    LISTEN      1000       190650      24293/java      
tcp6       0      0 :::8040                 :::*                    LISTEN      1000       190658      24293/java      
tcp6       0      0 :::8042                 :::*                    LISTEN      1000       190663      24293/java
```

The directory /app/hadoop/tmp/dfs contains just one folder - namesecondary - which is empty. The solutions I've seen here suggests to copy the namespaceID from /app/hadoop/tmp/dfs/name/current/VERSION to /app/hadoop/tmp/dfs/data/current/VERSION, but these directories where not created during namenode format.

I have lost hdfs and all data on it because the deamons where running during namenode format.

Comment: Have you formatted the namenode?

Comment: yes. i just edited my question now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. edit hdfs-site.xml as follows:

   ```
   <property>
   <name>dfs.replication</name>
     <value>1</value>
     <description>Default block replication.
     The actual number of replications can be specified when the file is created.
     The default is used if replication is not specified in create time.
     </description>
    </property>
    <property>
      <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
     <value>/app/hadoop/tmp/dfs/name</value>
   <final>true</final>
    </property>
    <property>
      <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
   <value>/app/hadoop/tmp/dfs/data</value>
   <final>true</final>
    </property>
   ```
2. sudo -rm -r -f /app/hadoop/tmp
3. sudo mkdir chown username:hadoopgroup /app/hadoop/tmp
4. stop-all.sh
5. hadoop namenode -format
6. jps

Solution found in https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/chennaihug/g_uJVIjykXk, but made some alterations.